# Angular, basic test not working

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Controller:

```
angular.module('ngApp', [
    'templates-app',
    'templates-common',
    'ngApp.home',
    'ui.router'
])

.config(function myAppConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})

.run(function run() {})

.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (angular.isDefined(toState.data.pageTitle)) {
            $scope.pageTitle = toState.data.pageTitle + ' | App';
        }
    });
});
```

Test:

```
describe('AppCtrl', function() {

    beforeEach(module('ngApp'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.pageTitle', function() {
        it('should set pageTitle', inject(function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var AppCtrl = $controller('AppCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        }));
    });
});
```

I am not testing anything right now, just loading the controller. However this fails

```
Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.2) AppCtrl $scope.pageTitle should set pageTitle FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at new AppCtrl (/src/app/app.js:15:9)
        at invoke (/vendor/angular/angular.js:4203:17)
        at Object.instantiate (/vendor/angular/angular.js:4211:27)
        at /vendor/angular/angular.js:8501:28
        at /vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1878:12
        at Object.<anonymous> (/src/app/app.spec.js:14:19)
        at Object.invoke (/vendor/angular/angular.js:4203:17)
        at Object.workFn (/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2436:20)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2407:25)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/src/app/app.spec.js:12:30)
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/src/app/app.spec.js:11:2)
        at /src/app/app.spec.js:1:1
```

Any ideas whats wrong with my test setup?

Actual test:

```
describe('$scope.pageTitle', function() {
    it('should be defiend after stateChange', inject(function() {
        var $scope = {};
        var AppCtrl = createController('AppCtrl');
        scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', {
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'bar'
            }
        });
        expect(scope.pageTitle).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

Comment: can you create a plnker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the scope from the `$rootScope` and inject it:

```
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, $rootScope) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        createController = function (ctrlName) {
          return $controller(ctrlName, {
            '$scope': scope
         });
       };
    }));
```

In this way you can use the `createController` function for the purpose and using:

```
var AppCtrl = createController('AppCtrl');
```

For having the controller.

Here is a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lbs6sk0k/2/

**EDIT**: where is `$scope` empty?
if I put a `console.log` here:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl($scope) {
    console.log($scope);
```

I can see this:

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

Set the the scope as a global variable:

```
describe('AppCtrl', function () {

    beforeEach(module('ngApp'));
    var $controller;
    var scope;
```

Then, in you test case, you can use it:

```
it('should set pageTitle', inject(function () {
    var $scope = scope;
```

Updated jsfiddle with your new test case: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbs6sk0k/3/

Comment: I mean in the test file, the "$scope" is empty but "scope" not. See my updated question. I want to actually test if pageTitle was set in the scope when an event was fired.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the scope you're injecting into the controller and the $scope.$on... . Try this:

```
describe('AppCtrl', function() {

beforeEach(module('ngApp'));

var $controller, $scope;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
}));

describe('$scope.pageTitle', function() {
    it('should set pageTitle', inject(function() {            
        var AppCtrl = $controller('AppCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    }));
});
});
```

Comment: I get Unknown provider: $_rootScope_Provider <- $_rootScope_

Comment: It seems I messed up a bit (it's been a while since I last wrote a controller test). The answer of the below code is the correct one. To explain the problem: The scope you're creating is just an empty object without any functions. This would be fine if you are just putting stuff on it but since you're using $on you need an actual scope. This is what the $rootScope.new() gives you